# PUT request with using Ajax(processing Spring)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to send PUT request with using Ajax. I send request with necessary information: newNavigation.

**PUT request:**

```
var newNavigation;
var newInputNavigation = document.getElementById('newInputNavigation');
newNavigation = newInputNavigation.value;

function editNavigation() {
    var prefix = '/airline/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: prefix +'flights/' + idAction.replace('edit',''),
        data: {
            navigation: newNavigation
        },
        success: function(receive) {
            $("#adminTable").empty();
            $("#informationP").replaceWith(receive);
            $("#hiddenLi").removeAttr('style');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error edited flight');
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
  private final String prefix = "/airline/";

 @RequestMapping(value = prefix + "/flights/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateFlight(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam("navigation") String navigation) {
        String returnText = "Flight edited successful";
        String str1 = navigation;
        String str2 = id;
        return returnText;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
 PUT http://localhost:8080/airline/flights/11 400 ()
```

**Questions:**

How send PUT request with necessary data(newNavigation)?

How get data(newNavigation) in Spring controller?

**EDIT:**

*Added NavigationDTO:*

```
public class NavigationDTO implements Serializable{
    public String navigation;
    public NavigationDTO() {
        super();
    }
}
```

*Changed controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = prefix + "/flights/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateFlight(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody NavigationDTO navigation) {
        String returnText = "Flight edited successful";
        String str1 = navigation.navigation;
        String str2 = id;
        return returnText;
    }
```

*Error:*

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/airline/flights/8 415 ()
```

Comment: what is the value of your prefix?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa     private final String prefix = "/airline/";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestParam("navigation")
```

RequestParam means that your navigation is a parameter in the request header which is not the case, the navigation is in your payload so you need to deserialize it.

Spring used Jackson, you need to create a POJO class with navigation as a parameter in it, the class should be serializable.

In your method use @RequestBody which stores the parsed payload in an object

```
 public String updateFlight(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody NavigationDto navigation) { //NavigationDto is the Pojo class
```

then you can easily access the navigation attribute from the object "navigation"

Comment: you need to include your content type in your ajax request, it should be application/json